# Huge category CSV import does not work

Tags: categories, import, csv

I have a 1.5 MB (with about 20.000 line) CSV file and I would like to import this into my new WordPress site. The code below does not create all of the categories, only some of them. I already increased the following settings for PHP:

```
max_execution_time = 2000
max_input_time = 2000
max_input_vars = 20000
memory_limit = 1024M
```

Can someone help me with what's wrong?

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '2000');
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wpse_57865_activation_run');

function wpse_57865_activation_run()
{
    $file = file_get_contents( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . 'categories.csv' );
    $data = array_map( "str_getcsv", preg_split( '/\r*\n+|\r+/', $file ) );

    if( count($data) < 1)
        return;

    foreach( $data as $cat )
    {
        $cat_defaults = array(
          'cat_name' => $cat[0],
          'category_nicename' => $cat[1] 
        );

        wp_insert_category($cat_defaults);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll probably have better results if you split the CSV into multiple separate files.

Comment: I've tried it before, but it will take longer to code execution. The first piece execute in 30 seconds but the second about 10 minutes and does not create all of the categories.

Comment: Upping memory limit and particularly execution time is not the way to go since it can make the server vulnerable to certain attacks. Ideally, an asynchronous task should be used (as used by [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) for example) to process the task in chunks. [WP Background Processing](https://github.com/A5hleyRich/wp-background-processing) looks really good too. I've also used the [WP All Import](http://www.wpallimport.com/) plugin before, which quite nice. I think it would be able to handle your use case.